# I am getting java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException in this code. i am trying to use date class in java to print out date

Tags: java, class, date, exception, datetime-format

I am getting `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException` in this code. I am trying to use the `Date` class in Java to print out the date.

```
package numbersstatics;

public class Date {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Date d = new Date();

        String w = String.format("%tc",d);

        System.out.println(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is only code in your question, it will get removed soon. [Hurry](Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)

Comment: The `Date` class is long outdated and poorly designed. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Use for example like `String w = String.format("%tc", ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Ashkhabad")));`. On my computer it just gave `Fri Jun 08 17:32:25 TMT 2018`.

Answer (score 1):

`Date d = new Date()` here is the issue.

Your class also named `Date` and I didn't see any import. So you are basically creating the instance of your own class not `java.util.Date` instance.

Try to `import java.util.Date;`

Or try this code

```
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();

String w = String.format("%tc",d);

System.out.println(w);
```

Note: It is always nice to add stacktrace with the question or else it is hard to find the error.

Comment: Yeap, wrong `Date` imported, since I just tried OP example and it works provided you import the correct `Date`, `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String w = format.format(curDate);

System.out.println(w);
```

or this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.printf("Current time and date: %tc\n", cal);
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to inspire you to study and understand the error message in the exception. I get

> java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: c != numbersstatics.Date

`numbersstatics.Date` refers to the `Date` class in the `numbersstatics` package. The first thing to notice is that this is not the `Date` class in `java.util` that you may have intended. It’s your own class. So you may ask yourself why `String.format` complains about your own class.

For the sake of completeness `c` refers to the letter in your format specification `%tc`. So the message says that you cannot format your own `Date` class with `%tc`. This might make you aware that you had passed an instance of your own class to `String.format`.

### Date is outdated

While explicitly mentioning `java.util.Date` should make your code work, consider not. The `Date` class is long outdated and poorly designed. Today we have so much better in java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Use for example like

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    String w = String.format("%tc", zdt);
```

On my computer it just gave

> Sat Jun 09 18:03:44 IST 2018

You may also use a `DateTimeFormatter`, this is what most programmers do.

Allow me to add: if you named your own class the same as the class from `java.time` you were using, here `ZonedDateTime`, you would already at compile time be notified that your class didn’t have the `now` method that you were calling, which may be a bit clearer, and at least you wouldn’t have to wait until runtime to see it. While this is a little thing, it’s one example out of thousands where the modern classes are more helpful that the old-fashioned ones.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.